# My celery worker is only running one job at a time?

Tags: celery

I'm using Celery with Django. I've started a worker with the following command:

```
celery worker -A proj -l info --concurrency=20 -n worker1.%h
```

This is similar to the worker setup suggested in the [Celery documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html).

I have some tasks that run for 10 minutes, and some that run in milliseconds. The worker logs what it's doing to the terminal, and at times it's really obvious the worker is completing many tasks because there hundreds of log messages printed to the terminal every second. Other times, the worker seems to stop processing new tasks for several minutes at a time, and there are no log messages printed on the terminal. I have also confirmed with `celery -A proj inspect active` that only one task is being worked on at a time.

I would have expected to see 20 tasks being worked on simultaneously because of the `--concurrency=20` flag I used. Is my expectation correct? If so, why does each worker work on only one task at a time?

Comment: What are you doing in your tasks? any sleeps?  and are you sure celery hasn't just run out of tasks?

Comment: I am connecting to a database in all tasks. I am sure there are tasks (messages to use an AMQP term) waiting in the queue; there are thousands and the queue is growing.

Comment: Are you using a pool of connections and are you sure you have connections to the database available?

Comment: I am most likely experiencing this bug: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1845